# Non Domain IIS servers / Files hosted on Domain File Share

Tags: active-directory, iis, server-message-block, unc

Building a load balanced pile of IIS servers: Windows 2019, not domain joined.
I'd like to point them all to a share for the sites' content directory to [hopefully] simplify keeping them all in sync.

That share is domain based.

I can't seem to hit the magic combination of user credentials at the site level or app pool level to get anything working.

If I configure the Site "Connect as.." to be a domain account and hit "Test Settings..." I'll get a green check mark for Authentication but a Red X for Authorization (Path might not exist and could not be verified).

[image]
If I configure the Site "Connect as..." to be Application User / Pass through application and hit test I get Green on Authentication and yellow as Authorization (Cannot verify access to path).

Setting App Pool to run as a domain user results in an app pool that won't start.
Setting App Pool to run as a local user with the same name/pass as my domain user doesn't get me any further.

For what it is worth, I can browse to the share from a web server [after specifying proper domain creds] so I know I have basic SMB connectivity.

Am I missing something obvious or is this simply not possible?

Comment: This sounds like a fun challenge. Why are the IIS servers not joined to the domain?

Comment: Well, the idea is that they will be "cattle" behind a load balancer and spun up/down (and disposed) as needed.

Comment: Striving to make them cattle-like is good. But even cattle can be domain-joined, no?

Comment: Sure. And in this case I may not have a choice. Was hoping to avoid extra AD cleanup steps 
(I know, it isn't the end of the world and can be automated... but a guy likes to TRY to build something clean first...ya know?)